# Node app at Google app engine can't access Redis sentinel

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I m trying to use redis as data storage for performance. 
- app engine includes node app (using 'sentinel-redis' lib)
- compute engines include redis-server & redis-sentinel (provided by GCP deploy management)
- the strange thing is that : node app works normally without error on compute engine (not in app engine)
- **i guess need something firewall rules that allows app engine to access to subnet that includes redis instances..**

---

- here is deploy fail log:

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error:

...
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Unable to determine master for master

```
at onResponse (/app/node_modules/sentinel-redis/index.js:133:19)
at Immediate.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/sentinel-redis/index.js:117:33)
at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
```

...

Answer (score 0):

found out that :
i was trying to accesa to external IPs of redis instances.
solution was :
just let them located in same vpn
& use internal ip